# Different prices per state for product

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to run a query for the price of an item purchased by a customer. The issue is all products are built at a base level with a 'blank' state for example see below.

```
STATE PRODUCT PRICE
        X       5.00
OH      X       5.25 
CA      X       5.75
        Y       6.00
```

I would like to know if im getting somewhere with this type of case statement and where I would place this as this is going to be a JOIN statement

```
(case when a.state= b.state THEN a.state ELSE 'BLANK' END)
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT o.NAME, o.STATE, o.ITEM, i.RATE
FROM ORDERS o
LEFT JOIN ON ITEM_DESC i
o.ITEM = i.ITEM AND
CASE 
       WHEN o.state = i.state 
       THEN o.state
       ELSE NULL
       END = i.state
```

REVISED this works but NULL isnt working so I need something to replace that with to catch a blank field (field is empty/blank not NULL)

Comment: case when coalesce(state,'') ='' then 'blank' end, covers both empty state and NULL condition.

Comment: @radar... Where would I place this if its going to be part of a JOIN statement? Also what happens when there is a match?

Comment: can you post your other table and join that is being done, with out the complete details, it is difficult to say.

Comment: ,in your example, does product Y price applies to states all stages including OH, CA as it is blank?

Comment: @radar yes if it is blank than that means if there isnt a state to state match than the blank would be default. OH and CA were just examples since each state can have their own price. All other states will get the 5.00 X product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case rate is `null`, you can get the result for that by doing a correlated sub query in a `case` statement.

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cecb/5)**

```
SELECT o.NAME,
       o.STATE, 
       o.ITEM, 
       case when i.RATE is NULL 
            then ( select rate from item_desc 
                   where item = o.item
                   and coalesce(state,'') =''
                  )
            else i.RATE
            end as RATE
FROM ORDERS o
LEFT JOIN ITEM_DESC i
ON o.ITEM = i.ITEM
AND o.STATE = i.STATE
```